# Help with this differential equation, nonlinear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I solve the following Differential Equation

$\frac{dy}{dx}= \sqrt{x+y} $

Clearly, it is nonlinear and non homogeneous, I could not find the way to solve it with Bernoulli or to make it an exact differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $z=x+y$ which gives you
$$
{dz\over dx}=1+\sqrt z
$$
which is separable in variables. Then use the substitution $z=t^2$ to calculate
$$
\int{dz\over1+\sqrt z}
$$